# code igniter - sending search term and getting mysql results as json from php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, codeigniter

i'm new to CI,
working on a small search engine, i'll send data from client side using `Jquery` `$.post`

```
<script>
    var term=$('#search_term').val();
    $.post(search_url,{term:term},function(data){
       $("#ajax_response").append( JSON.stringify(data));
    });
</script>
```

and this is how i'm generating Json in CI controller

```
<?php 
function s() {
        $term = $_POST['term'];
        $result = $this -> search_model -> search($term);
        $cities=array();
        foreach ($result as $key => $bd) {
            if (!isset($cities[$bd['c_name']])) {
                $cities[$bd['c_name']]=array();
            }
            $cities[$bd['c_name']][]=$bd;
        }
        echo json_encode($cities);
     }

?>
```

and the json output i'm getting is

```
{"Siddapura":[
    {
        "b_id":"12",
        "c_id":"2",
        "b_name":"Sandige Mensu",
        "b_contactperson":"aaasdf",
        "b_area":"Siddapura Town",
        "c_name":"Siddapura"
    },
    {
        "b_id":"14",
        "c_id":"2",
        "b_name":"Hhhh",
        "b_contactperson":"asdfasfd",
        "b_area":"Siddapura Town",
        "c_name":"Siddapura"
    }],
    "Other":[
    {
        "b_id":"5",
        "c_id":"4",
        "b_name":"Prathvi Home Products",
        "b_contactperson":"Ganaraj Hegde",
        "b_area":"Other",
        "c_name":"Other"
    },
    {
        "b_id":"6",
        "c_id":"4",
        "b_name":"Innond Home Product",
        "b_contactperson":"Ganaraj Hegde",
        "b_area":"Other",
        "c_name":"Other"
    }
    ]}
```

Json object names are different every time according to search.
i want two outputs from this data.
1)[image: The result]

this is the result i wand to show
2) how many results in which areas...
[image: Filtering results]

need help in processing `json` data in `Jquery` and appending them to  `div` `id` `#ajax_response`.
thanks in advance.

Comment: please tell clearly what you want/

Comment: `2) how many results in which areas...` explain it.

Comment: sorry for my english wording, Object name Siddapura has two arrays,
and object name 'Other' has two two arrray, i want two show them. just look at that blue image i attached..

i want to show search results, and i dont know how to handle JSon data in jquery

Comment: You're probably better off implementing the data from your Controller into a view and using PHP to loop through the results like you'd do normally. $this->load->view has a third param TRUE/FALSE whether to return a string or output the object. Store the results of your view inside a variable and echo that inside the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your post response

```
$.post(
    search_url,
    {term:term},
    function(data){
       $('#div1').html(data.Siddapura[0]);
       $('#div2').html(data.Other[0]);
    }
);
```